# Drag and Drop view with pages

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-launcher

I'm looking for a custom view that will behave similar to the launcher app:

- Show multiple icons
- Support drag & drop
- Suport drag outside to delete
- Support multiple pages
- Indicate current page
- Work on Android pre version 3

Anyone knows about such a view?

Comment: this is not freelancing, also you can google it for this

Comment: Never thought it was.
I've been trying to create my own for several days now and never got it to really work...
Also, google didn't really help...